# How to recurse a String to validate that it contains only numbers after the first character

Tags: java, string, recursion, int

I need to create a ***recursive method*** that takes a **String** parameter.
I need to verify that the first letter in the string is a lowercase character, and then verify that everything that comes after the first letter is a number.

So it should be like this `a1234`.

I've tried creating a base case, smaller base case, and a general case, but can't seem to figure out the right way to style it:

```
public void digitCheck(String s) {

   if () //To Check that first character is a letter

   else if ()To check that everything after the first letter is a number

   else //Invalid
}
```

I need the code to report whether it's a valid string if the first character is a ***lower case letter*** and everything after that is a ***number***.

Example:
`a123` -> **valid**.
`ab123` -> **invalid**.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hint: try keeping track of which index you're at in the string as a parameter to the recursive function. By the way, this is a really contrived problem: IRL, you'd never check a string like this, character by character because it'll blow the stack on large strings and it's slow and difficult to reason about. A regex like `^[A-Za-z]\d*$` is much cleaner for validating this property.

Comment: @ggorlen So should I add say a helper method that takes an additional parameter such as (String word, int index) and then call the helper method in the above method?

Comment: That sounds like a good plan! If you're not allowed to use a helper, consider taking substrings of the string on each call, the base case being your string length is 0, your alpha case being length 1, and every other longer string must match the last character to a digit.

Comment: What would the syntax be for checking to see if a position in the string is a digit? @ggorlen

Comment: `myString.charAt(index);`, although that's a good question to practice your google-fu on (an invaluable coding skill).

Answer (score 1):

Use the String.matches() method:

```
boolean valid = s.matches(".\\d+");
```

Comment: it doesn't validate if the first letter is lower case or it is even absent.

Comment: OP should look at Pattern to find full regex, such as  "[a-z]\\d+"

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem with recursion for your pattern you can do:

- start from the end and
- check the last element
- remove the last element
- call all remaining part

It should be checking until one element will be passed to the method -> make final validation if it is a lower letter.

Also, [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class is used from [commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library.

Here is code snippet:

```
public class StringValidationDemo {
    public boolean validateStringRecursive(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            return StringUtils.isAlpha(str) && StringUtils.isAllLowerCase(str);
        }

        String lastIndex = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
        return StringUtils.isNumeric(lastIndex)
                && validateStringRecursive(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("a123", "ab123", "123ab", "A123", "aaa", "123");

        StringValidationDemo demo = new StringValidationDemo();
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.printf("validation for: %s = %s\n",
                    word, demo.validateStringRecursive(word));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
validation for: a123 = true
validation for: ab123 = false
validation for: 123ab = false
validation for: A123 = false
validation for: aaa = false
validation for: 123 = false
```

Comment: For this problem I sadly have to use recursion, and aren't allowed anything else

Comment: @UltamaniaHD I updated the answer with the recursive solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could ommit the first character in the string, and then just check with Integer.parseInt(String). so it would look something like:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    try {
        double d = Integer.parseInt(String);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void DoStuff(String string){
    if (isNumeratic(string.substring(1)) //ommits first
    {
      ///yourstuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Input string might be too long to fit in an int, but still contain only digits.